# Android 9 always calls onStopJob right after onStartJob returns with true

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jobscheduler

I have a scheduled job implemented as follows:

```
class RefreshImageService : JobService() {
    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        info { "RefreshImage: start job" }
        appCoroScope.launch {
            fetchImageAndUpdateWidget()
            info { "RefreshImage: finished" }
            jobFinished(params, false)
        }
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters): Boolean {
        info { "RefreshImage: stop job" }
        return true
    }
}
```

In the logs I always see `RefreshImage: stop job` immediately after `RefreshImage: start job` and then, later on, `RefreshImage: finished`, which means Android released my wakelock right away and my service was allowed to finish only by chance. It would probably be killed if the HTTP request took a bit longer.

This is how I declare the service:

```
<service
    android:name=".RefreshImageService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
/>
```

And this is how I schedule it:

```
val jobInfo = JobInfo.Builder(refreshImageJobId, 
        ComponentName(context, RefreshImageService::class.java))
    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
    .setMinimumLatency(latencyMillis)
    .setOverrideDeadline(HOUR_IN_MILLIS)
    .build()
context.jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or maybe a workaround that would make Android behave properly?

Comment: If `fetchImageAndUpdateWidget()` is asynchronous you have to pass a callback method to it and call `jobFinished` from that callback. Otherwise `jobFinished` might be called before `fetchImageAndUpdateWidget` is done...

Comment: It's a suspend fun, so it's all in proper order. But I think I foumd my problem, the function also reschedules the job before the HTTP fetch to ensure it runs again even if killed. However, scheduling a job automatically stops the current job.

Comment: Makes sense. The job scheduler is supposed to make your life easier and save you boilerplate code like ensuring things go properly :) It's functionally and api pretty much covers it.. I warmly suggest you start playing with the new WorkManager, it's api is quite similar and it covers more android sdk versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't make my life easy. I fetch an image in a non-recurring job because I must schedule the next fetch based on the current image's Last-Modified timestamp. For this case I get no guarantee that my process won't be killed before it reaches the rescheduling code, and then the job never runs again. But if I pre-emptively schedule it for a retry, then it gives me these other problems.

Answer (score 2):

I realized the problem lies within `fetchImageAndUpdateWidget()` which must also deal with scheduling the next image fetch based on the `Last-Modified` header of the current HTTP result. If Android decides to kill my job before it reaches the scheduling code, my job will never run again.

To prevent this, I added a line that provisionally schedules the job before making the HTTP request. That, however, caused Android to try to immediately stop my current job, as per the documentation of `JobScheduler.schedule()`:

> If a job with the given ID is currently running, it will be stopped.

This leaves me without an option to robustly implement my scheduling behavior. I had to resort to using another scheduled job just to check whether my primary job lost its schedule.